# Can't increment counter and not sure if correct comparison of background and drawable

Tags: android, button, drawable, counter

I'm trying to check if a corresponding text is the same with the image that is displayed in a button.

For example, the String "heart" is displayed, i want to know if the image displayed on the button is an image of heart, and if the right image is loaded, when you click the button, the counter will increment.

```
package com.example.simplegame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Game extends Activity {
public int correct = 0;

ArrayList<Integer> ShapesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

ArrayList<String> ShapestoFind = new ArrayList<String>();
TextView Answer;
Button Check;
Button img1;
Button img2;
Button img3;
Button img4;
Button img5;
Button img6;
Button img7;
Button img8;
Button img9;
Random rand = new Random();
public String Shape;
Drawable bgImg1;

private int myImg1;
private int myImg2;
private int myImg3;
private int myImg4;
private int myImg5;
private int myImg6;
private int myImg7;
private int myImg8;
private int myImg9;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    ShapesArray.add(R.drawable.circle);
    ShapesArray.add(R.drawable.heart);
    ShapesArray.add(R.drawable.square);
    ShapesArray.add(R.drawable.triangle);

    ShapestoFind.add("Heart");
    ShapestoFind.add("Circle");
    ShapestoFind.add("Triangle");
    ShapestoFind.add("Square");     

    int size = ShapesArray.size();


    final TextView PName = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.choice);



        Answer = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textAnswer);

   img1 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
   img2 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button2);
   img3 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button3);
   img4 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button4);
   img5 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button5);
   img6 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button6);
   img7 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button7);
   img8 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button8);
   img9 = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button9);
   Check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);


   int rndInt = rand.nextInt(size);
   Shape = ShapestoFind.get(rndInt);

   PName.setText(Shape);
   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);
   img1.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(0));

   this.myImg1 = ShapesArray.get(0);

   img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


       public void onClick(View v){

       if(Shape.equals("Heart")){
           if(myImg1 == R.drawable.heart){
               correct++;
           } 


       }

       else if(Shape.equals("Circle")){
           if(myImg1 == R.drawable.circle){
               correct++;
           }
       }

       else if(Shape.equals("Square")){
           if(myImg1 == R.drawable.square){

               correct++;
           }
       }

       else if(Shape.equals("Triangle")){
           if(myImg1 == R.drawable.triangle){

               correct++;
           }
       }

   }
 });


   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);
   img2.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(1));


   this.myImg2 = ShapesArray.get(1);

   img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


       public void onClick(View v){

       if(Shape.equals("Heart")){
           if(myImg2 == R.drawable.heart){

               correct++;
           } 


       }

       if(Shape.equals("Circle")){
           if(img2.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.circle)){
               correct++;
           }
       }

       if(Shape.equals("Square")){
           if(img1.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.square)){

               correct++;
           }
       }

       if(Shape.equals("Triangle")){
           if(img1.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.triangle)){

               correct++;
           }
       }

   }
  });


   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);


   img3.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(0));


   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);
   img4.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(1));


   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);
   img5.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(0));


   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);
   img6.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(1));


   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);
   img7.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(0));


   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);
   img8.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(1));


   Collections.shuffle(ShapesArray);
   img9.setBackgroundResource(ShapesArray.get(0));

   this.myImg1=R.drawable.heart;








   Check.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {


            Answer.setText(Integer.toString(correct));


        } 
     });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

I'm still kinda new to Android. I don't know if what I want is possible. Can Someone Please help. :(

Comment: What happens when you try this piece of code?

Comment: the counter "correct" does not increment even if the background image is correct. if I remove the inner "if" statement and just place the counter on the first "if", the counter increments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare a Drawable with a Resource ID, which is what you are doing in:

```
if(img1.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.heart)){
    ...
```

Maybe what you want is to save the Resource ID of the background when you set it, like:

```
this.mImg1Bg = R.drawable.heart;
img1.setBackground(this.mImg1Bg);
```

And then on the onClick() you test with:

```
if(this.mImg1Bg == R.drawable.heart) {
    ...
```

**EDIT:**

Now with the entire code it is easier.

I will assume that you have this at the end of onCreate():

```
this.myImg1=R.drawable.heart;
```

just for testing purposes, as you are redefining it as it was set already.

Now you have another problem with the string test. Shape variable is not what you want to test. Maybe if you test it like:

```
public void onClick(View v){

    String txt = ((Button)v).getText();
    if(txt.equals("Heart")){
        if(myImg1 == R.drawable.heart){
            correct++;
        } 
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't know what exactly you are showing in your Activity, but it seems to me that you could simplify a lot if you used:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> shapes;
shapes.put("Heart", R.drawable.heart);
...
```

to store the shapes strings and relation to resources.

An ArrayList of Pair's to store the combinations  on the buttons:

```
ArrayList<Pair<Integer,String>> buts;
buts.add(new Pair<Integer,String>(R.drawable.heart, "Heart"));
...
```

Set a tag on each button view to know which button number was clicked:

```
img1.setTag(1);
...
```

Then assign the same OnClickListener to all buttons. For instance by implementing the interface by your Activity, like:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

...

    img1.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
```

And check the onClick() like this:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int res = buts.get((Integer)v.getTag()).first;
        String txt = buts.get((Integer)v.getTag()).second;
        if(res == shapes.get(txt)) {
            correct++;
        } 
    }
```

And then don't forget to assign the correct to some UI TextView so you can view the result.

Comment: Additional information, the background of my button is changed randomly. I used collections.shuffle to randomize my background. however i tried this but still the counter does not increment.

Comment: I tried this code that you posted but still does not increment.

Comment: Update: The counter now increments if The string displayed is "heart" and whatever image is loaded in the button. I want to check if the text is the same with the image loaded. If other strings are displayed like "circle", the counter does not increment.

Comment: The code I posted works. It must be some problem when you save the background resource id. I need to see your code so I can help you, sorry...

Comment: I get an error NullPointerException on the line

     shapes.put("Heart", R.drawable.heart);

Comment: Somehow I got my code to work although not using Hashmap. But thanks for showing HashMap so i had a better idea on how to implement it correctly.